# Is the sentence "Read with an affectionate tone" correct?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I want to send a text message to someone and after a phrase, I tend to write between parenthesis: "Read with an affectionate tone". for example:

> Your message means so much to me. (**Read with an affectionate tone**)

Is the sentence in parenthesis correct? Is the `an` in the sentence necessary?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. "Tone" is a countable noun, thus it takes the indefinite articles "a" or "an" depending on if the word right after the article starts with a vowel. (in this case, the first sound of "affectionate" is a vowel so use "an")

Comment: Thanks. Does the sentence sound natural? Or is it something odd? I'll appreciate if you point it in your answer too.